# How to write nested loop and avoid that it overwrites data?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nested-loops, tweepy

### I don't get it

Hi all,
I'm trying to get the recent tweets from multiple users.
There for i created a nested Loop, but my problem is that it overwrites "berlintweets".
So the Loop works, but it should add the data instead of overwriting it.

Really any help or advice would be highly appreciated.
I'm a total beginner, who's proud that he made it this far.. but now I'm sadly stuck and don't really know what i can do / change anymore.

Thank you all in advance!

```py
import tweepy
import config
import pandas as pd

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=config.BEARER_TOKEN)
Liste_Namen = pd.read_csv('Namen.csv', delimiter=',')
tweet_id_list = [""]
tweet_text_list = [""]
tweet_created_list = [""]
berlintweet = [""]

for user_name in Liste_Namen['ids']:
    berlintweet = tweepy.Paginator(client.get_users_tweets, id=user_name, exclude= ["replies", "retweets"], tweet_fields=["created_at"], max_results=100).flatten(limit=200)

    for tweet in berlintweet:
        tweet_id_list.append(tweet.id)
        tweet_text_list.append(tweet)
        tweet_created_list.append(tweet.created_at)

df = pd.DataFrame({
'name': config.USER_ID,
'tweet_id': tweet_id_list,
'tweet_text': tweet_text_list,
'tweet_created': tweet_created_list,

})
df.to_csv('BerlinTest2.csv', sep=',', index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Heres what I do when this get complicated:  Identify problems then reduce and simplify without changing the output. Big emphasis on reduction. Less is way more and it will slowly become clear the actual issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to append to `berlintweet`, just as you append to your other lists, such as `tweet_id_list`:

```
    page = tweepy.Paginator(
        client.get_users_tweets, 
        id=user_name, 
        exclude=["replies", "retweets"], 
        tweet_fields=["created_at"], 
        max_results=100)    
    berlintweet.append(page.flatten(limit=200))
```

For more information, the following might be useful to you:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types

It did not immediately become apparent to me what `flatten()` returns, but the name suggest to me that it's a list (https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/v2_pagination.html). However, you can also pass a generator to `append()`. It should modify the list it's called on in-place.

Also, you initialize `tweet_id_list` with a string and then attempt to access `.id` of each element, which will not work. A string does not have `.id`. The same issue applies to `berlintweet = [""]`. You want to initialize it with `berlintweet = []`. This is either a copy-paste error or you are still unclear how to initialize a variable with an empty list. An empty list is `[]`, while `[""]` means a list with an empty string as only element. Actually, it might apply to all four of your lists, as I suspect there is no good reason to have an empty string in there, unless it is some requirements external to this portion of the code.

When you append the tweet texts to `tweet_text_list`, you probably want to write `tweet.text`. I believe that's what the documentation states, but I do not have the ability to test out the code right now, as I do not have a Twitter account.

For other readers of this answer, the documentation of the available fields for a tweet are here:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/fields

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/v2_models.html#tweet

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @BananaMango. I already tried to append berlintweet in a similar way.. the problem is that i than receive the following error :     tweet_id_list.append(tweet.id)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: (But in general the reference to the official python documentation looks pretty useful and i will read it.. thank you for it!)

Comment: Oh, but that's because you initialize it with a string. It should be an empty list, as I realize just now, as you try to access the member ".id". Initialize it with [], not [""]. If you try that, I could add that to my answer. I still think my answer so far applies, but there are several issues with the code, it appears.

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked.. apperantly my problem was that i did not wrote the code "clean". After cleaning it up it worked!

Comment: Oh and you dont need to append berlintweets, as it is a nested for loop

Comment: Oh, that's true. You just use it to then copy the content of the tweets (of each page) to the various lists you have created. It might be unnecessary but I suppose it works.